# Springboard-like animation for deleting UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, springboard

I am trying to figure out a way to animate the deletion of a `UICollectionViewCell` similarly to springboard in iOS 7. The deleted cell should shrink into nothingness and the remaining cells should slide over to fill its place (the sliding is the important part). I have tried:

• Setting the frame of each cell to the frame of the previous cell, like so:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
CGRect rect = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i - 1 inSection:0]].frame;      
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    cell.frame = rect;
}];
```

But this did not work, as the cells did not move at all.

• Both of the following:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
} completion:nil];
```

and

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
}];
```

But these make the cells crossfade to their required spots, not slide.

I also found [this project](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sespringboard), which uses the following:

```
for (int i = index+1; i<[items count]; i++) {
    SEMenuItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:i];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

        if (i < index + remainingNumberOfItemsInPage) {

            int intVal = item.frame.origin.x;
            if (intVal %3== 0)
                [item setFrame:CGRectMake(item.frame.origin.x+2*item.frame.size.width, item.frame.origin.y-item.frame.size.height-5, item.frame.size.width, item.frame.size.height)];
            else
                [item setFrame:CGRectMake(item.frame.origin.x-item.frame.size.width, item.frame.origin.y, item.frame.size.width, item.frame.size.height)];
        }

        [item updateTag:item.tag-1];
    }];
}
```

However, it is not in a `UICollectionView`, so it does not help me.

*Note:* I am doing this on an iPad, just in case it matters to you.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wish I could post a full answer, because I've done something like this. Just set the size of the cell to `CGSizeZero` and it's origin to the point previously the `center` of the cell in the following method https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  Implement:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // might need to replace self with super

    attr.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);

    return attr;
}
```

Comment: `attr.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);` works. The other doesn't actually shrink the size of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to duci9y's answer, (using `attr.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);`), the following makes the tiles slide. I can't believe I didn't think of this before.

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    [dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: That may cause animation errors. I suggest you change the `center` property of `attr` to go off the screen along with the `transform` to get the desired effect.